# Getting different numbers after sending an unsigned int 8-9 times between Arduinos via Serial

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano

I am trying to transfer `unsigned int` values between 2 Arduinos. When sending `61805` for the first 8-9 times, I am getting 61805.  But after then after these numbers: 61937 28013 61937.

Sender's code:

```cpp
unsigned int s = 0;

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin(9600) ;
}

void loop()
{
  s = 61805;
  Serial.write(highByte(s)) ;
  Serial.write(lowByte(s));
}
```

Receiver's code:

```
unsigned int upperByte, lowerByte, r=0,p=0;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
} 

void loop () 
{
  if (Serial.available() > 1)
  {
    upperByte = Serial.read();
    lowerByte = Serial.read();
  }

  r = (upperByte << 8) + lowerByte;
  Serial.println(r);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no flow control on the Uno and Nano serial and you are sending fast enough that bytes are being dropped, and there's no way your protocol or lack of one demarcates separate messages (separate numbers).

This will become more clear if you write your numbers in hexadecimal:

| Dec | Hex |
| --- | --- |
| 61805 | 0xf16d |
| 61937 | 0xf1f1 |
| 28013 | 0x6d6d |
| 61937 | 0xf1f1 |

Adding a delay between messages can serve to separate the messages if the receiving side makes use of a timeout and can prevent the receiving side from being overwhelmed with data.

If you don't want to use time to slow down and separate your data, you can change what is sent instead.  One idea is to have the receiver actively request data when it's ready to receive some. The receiver should expect only entire messages between requests, and if anything gets garbled, it can just read whatever data has come in and throw it out before the next request.

Your messages can also be separated by some characters that aren't part of the messages themselves.  A common way to do that is just to encode your numbers as separate text lines, the line terminator `\n` serving as the separator between messages.

I have not tested these yet, but here are some very minimal modifications to your code that approach having a protocol with fewer of these problems:

Sender:

```cpp
void setup () {   
  Serial.begin(9600);
} 

void loop() {
  // await message request
  while(Serial.read() != '.') {
  }

  //
  const unsigned int s = 61805;
  Serial.write(highByte(s)) ;
  Serial.write(lowByte(s));
}
```

Receiver:

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
} 


void loop () {
  // request message
  Serial.write('.'); 


  // await two-byte response
  const unsigned long request_sent = millis();
  while (Serial.available() < 2 && millis() - request_sent < 1000) {
  }


  if (Serial.available() != 0) {
    if (Serial.available() == 2) {
      // two byte response receive 
      const unsigned upperByte = Serial.read();
      const unsigned lowerByte = Serial.read();
      const unsigned r = (upperByte << 8) + lowerByte;
      Serial.println(r);
    }  else {
      // Something went wrong, too or too few bytes received;
      // throw them out and start over.
      delay(100);
      while (Serial.read() != -1) {}
    }
  }
}
```

It's a long way from doing it properly, but it should behave at least better than what you started with.  There's a lot to designing even simple protocols.  Typically there are start and end frame bytes, a checksum or CRC, a message number counter, etc.

Comment: thanks brother it worked .....thanks a lot....

Comment: We use to send 8,N,2 and receive on 8,N,1. That gave us an extra bit time to adjust for clock skew.

Answer (score 0):

This line of the receiver's code:

```cpp
Serial.println(r);
```

is transmitting 7 bytes (5 digits, CR and LF). At 9600/8N1, each byte
takes 1.04 ms, so the whole message is transmitted in 7.28 ms. In the
meantime, the sender is sending 2-byte messages at full speed (no pause
between the bytes). The receiver thus gets a new message every 2.08 ms.

So, this receiver is given a new message to relay every 2.08 ms, and it
needs 7.28 ms to relay each message. Something has to give...

The reason it works in the beginning is that the receiver has a buffer
where it stores the bytes that have been received, and another one for
the bytes that have been made ready for transmission. As long as there
is room in those buffers, everything works fine. The transmit buffer
fill-up first, as it gets 7 bytes to transmit every 2.08 ms. Once it's
full, `Serial.println()` becomes a *blocking* function: it has to wait
for the buffer to have enough room. Your `loop()` then slows down to
match the speed of the transmission, which means you do not read the
receive buffer often enough. Then the receive buffer fills up, and you
start loosing bytes.

Comment: thanks brother for you effort.... nicely explained... got the point